# How do I retrieve the Business Manager ID from Facebook graph api using ad account id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

There seems to be nothing in the documentation on how this is achieved.

Using the graph api explorer to achieve this would be of huge help
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A described in the [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/#fields), you can request the `business` field:

> [business](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/business/): The [Business Manager](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager), if this ad account is owned
>   by one

As example:

> curl -i -X GET \ 
>   "https://graph.facebook.com/vX.X/act_XXX?fields=business&access_token="

```
{
  "business": {
    "id": "XXXX",
    "name": "Acme"
  },
  "id": "act_XXXX"
}
```